# What is the appropriate abbreviation for "laboratoires" in French?

Tags: abréviations

In English, we use "lab" and "labs". In French is it "lab" and "labs" as well, or "labo"/"labos"?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In French, we'd rather say **Labo / Labos**.

But it's kind of familiar, don't use it during a presentation or a report since abbreviations are mostly discouraged in that.

Comment: While it's kind of familiar and I wouldn't use it in a report either, I think using it in a presentation is perfectly fine.

Comment: Lab and labs are also perfectly fine in French...

Comment: @stbr I never heard that in France.

Comment: @AmiralPatate Les étudiants l'utilisent souvent pour dire qu'ils ont un cours pratique dans un laboratoire *J'ai un lab ce matin*, les professionnels également.